# Silverlight: Custom Radio button

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to develop a custom radio button that looks like a two-option button control that looks somewhat as shown below with toggling of highlighted state. Not sure where to start.

[image]

Is there any such controls already available that I can use.

Comment: Define "available"? In the standard SDK, Examples, Free, Opensource, commercial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here is a brief overview of what you will need to do ...

1. Firstly, you will need to change the `ControlTemplate` for the existing `RadioButton` control. There are lots of tutorials available that describe this,, for example [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-7-using-control-templates-to-customize-a-control-s-look-and-feel.aspx).
2. Replace the standard template with some suitable markup for your illustration above. Perhaps a two column `Grid`?
3. Within each `Grid` cell add a Rectangle, one behind Option1, and the other behind Option2
4. Use the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(VS.95).aspx) to change the `Fill` property of each `Rectangle` based on the controls current `VisualState`. i.e. when `Pressed` toggle the background colours.

The steps above should help you achieve your goal. Please read the linked web pages and the Silverlight documentation. If you are still struggling after that,, come back and ask another question.